# Laravel vendor publish scout doesn't publish scout.php in the config folder

Tags: laravel-5

After running,`composer require laravel/scout`

Added this in the config/app.php configuration file:

```
Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider::class,
```

Finally

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider"
```

The problem is it doesn't publish the scout.php file in the config folder...

Answer (score 3):

Ok, to see you are doing something wrong, just use php artisan vendor:publish, without any parameter.

it will publish all available provides. if it doesn't work there should be an issue with the package, consider  re-install  it.

Comment: I don't believe that always works. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to manually copy and create the config file:

from:
    /vendor/laravel/scout/config/scout.php

to:
    /config/scout.php

Comment: Nice to know the work around to keep things going, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but using **Lumen** and the output in my case it was something like this:

```
Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/scout v3.0.7
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/scout v3.0.6
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/scout v3.0.5
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/scout v3.0.4
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/scout v3.0.3
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/scout v3.0.2
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/scout v3.0.1
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/scout v3.0.0
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/scout 3.0.x-dev
- Conclusion: remove illuminate/bus v5.3.23
- Installation request for laravel/scout ^3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/scout[3.0.x-dev, v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7].
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/bus v5.3.23
- laravel/scout 3.0.x-dev requires illuminate/bus ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/bus[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.9].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/bus[5.4.x-dev, v5.3.23].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/bus[5.5.x-dev, v5.3.23].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/bus[v5.4.0, v5.3.23].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/bus[v5.4.13, v5.3.23].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/bus[v5.4.17, v5.3.23].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/bus[v5.4.19, v5.3.23].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/bus[v5.4.27, v5.3.23].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/bus[v5.4.9, v5.3.23].
- Installation request for illuminate/bus (locked at v5.3.23) -> satisfiable by illuminate/bus[v5.3.23].
```

Scout is for be used in version **5.4**, So in the file *composer.json* change the version in the following line:

```
"laravel/lumen-framework": "5.4.*"
```

after this just run:

```
   composer dump-autoload
   composer update 
   composer require laravel/scout
```

and for finish:

```
  php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider"
```

Well this is the case for Lumen, but if is not your case, Try to update the Laravel version on composer file, and then update before install scout.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have cached your config using `artisan config:cache`. To solve it clear the config cache (by running `artisan config:cache` again). Then retry the vendor publish command.